# Pass field on node/x/edit to a view, using global field / php?

Tags: views, entities

I just want to pass a field from a node being edited- to a view- that I am using to provide a select list for another field on that same node, that is an an entity reference.

And I think I could maybe do that by using a global field on the view, with php- to get the field I want, from the node being edited- into the view?